# Access list items -python

Tags: python

```
result1 = [prg_count,prg_mt_count,dnt_prg_count,excld_count]
total_students = prg_count + prg_mt_count + dnt_prg_count + excld_count
result2 = ["Progress", "Progress(MT)", "Do not Progress(MT)", "Exclude"]

def histogram (list1):
    for i in range (len(list1)):
        for j in range (list1[i]):
            print("*",end="")
        print("")

print('_' * 30)
print("Horizontal Histogram")
histogram (result1)
print(total_students, "outcomes in total")
print('_' * 30)
```

I want to print the items in the `result2` list, one by one with their histogram value.
Histogram value changes according to user inputs and they're assigned to `result1` list items.

what I'm trying to get;

```
Progress  : * 
Progress(MT)  : * 
Do not Progress(MT) : ** 
Excluded 1 : *
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. What does user input have to do with printing the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some improvements to your code, instead of loop for `*` printing I used `'*' * count`, same like you did for horizontal line `'_' * 30`, also printed names of histogram keys as you wished in your Question, plus used string's method `.ljust(21)` which adds extra spaces to align several strings to the same width.

Also as an example I showed histogram values `1, 5, 2, 3`, see my [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXsV8.png) after code below.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBPT4QwEMXv/RSTXihrNQLxYrI3TfZi4sGb2RAW2F0MdEg7JLpfHqfyZ0HtpfPrvLy@mfaLzmiSvm/tKc2xM6TBlw1NVBhKF83yM6@LAWALkYYHDbGGRNjSdTVF/Ph@la@s1k4Lo70gpKxOHXVFacixx6yDm1UexpUN88JoDBH7EPLV4onZSQ1zrV7eQs9PCAYJfj8/sxVHkHshivII58oRC7IGVM0lD@uvOHwUwOeIFjINB6gMXKr2P4k/ra0MqcNd/dE5UnEUcuRgE8AGslCIoRtsPSf34chyh7a6oOGlwG4KIaducDup54Bq3L6GcQN/tQOvF80jY0c5NqXzU/w0r99Mofr@Gw)

```py
prg_count, prg_mt_count, dnt_prg_count, excld_count = 1, 5, 2, 3
result1 = [prg_count,prg_mt_count,dnt_prg_count,excld_count]
total_students = prg_count + prg_mt_count + dnt_prg_count + excld_count
result2 = ["Progress", "Progress(MT)", "Do not Progress(MT)", "Exclude"]

def histogram (list1, list2):
    for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
        print(b.ljust(21) + '*' * a)

print('=' * 30)
print("Horizontal Histogram")
print('-' * 30)
histogram(result1, result2)
print('-' * 30)
print(total_students, "outcomes in total")
print('=' * 30)
```

Output:

```
==============================
Horizontal Histogram
------------------------------
Progress             *
Progress(MT)         *****
Do not Progress(MT)  **
Exclude              ***
------------------------------
11 outcomes in total
==============================
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I think I know what you are saying. If you want to print the titles to the values (as I think your desired output says) you need to pass your titles in.

```
result1 = [5, 4, 2, 3]
total_students = sum(result1)
result2 = ["Progress","Progress(MT)","Do not Progress(MT)","Exclude"]

def histogram(result2, result1):
    for i in range(len(result2)):
        print(result2[i], end=" ")
        for j in range(result1[i]):
            print('*', end="")
        print('')



print('_' * 30)
print("Horizontal Histogram")
histogram (result2, result1)
print(total_students, "outcomes in total")
print('_' * 30)
```

If you want to make it more succinct you can do this instead.

```
output = zip(result2, result1)
def histogram(list1):
    for title, value in list1:
        print(f"{title:20} {''.join(['*' for i in range(value)])}\n")
histogram(output)
```